# Variable truncates when using messagebox

Tags: vb.net

I have a strange problem here. In my code, variable b string, has the value "Test Test Test". This value we can see while debugging the variable as well as in the text visualizer.

Now the problem is, if I show the same string using Messagebox, the value is just "Test". What can I do here to get the complete value.

I am converting from an ebcdic encoded bytes to corresponding utf8 string and doing the above operation. Any thoughts. below is my sample code.

```
Dim hex As String = "e385a2a300000000e385a2a3000000e385a2a3"
Dim raw As Byte() = New Byte((hex.Length / 2) - 1) {}

Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To raw.Length - 1
    raw(i) = Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring((i * 2), 2), &H10)
Next i
Dim w As String = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(37).GetString(raw)
Dim raw1 As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(w)
Dim b As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw1)
MessageBox.Show(b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the byte array. You have 4 ASCII 0's after each "Test". ASCII character code 0 corresponds to nul, which is a string termination sequence. If you want spaces instead of nulls there...

```
Dim b As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(raw1).Replace(Chr(0), " ")
```

Comment: ASCII 0 is a string termination ONLY in MSGBOX, I remember it as an exception still in VB6, where it also truncated a string in the debug window when writing a ?variable

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the string "b" might contains some `control` character.

To test a control char in  string.

```
  For Each p As Char In b
     MsgBox(p & "   " & Char.IsControl(p) & "  " & AscW(p))
   Next
```

Use `String#Replace` to replace control chars.

```
 b = b.Replace(ChrW(0), " ")
 MsgBox(b)
```